# Simple String of 6-digits

Tags: combinatorics, inclusion-exclusion, combinatorics-on-words

This is the problem:

> A string of 6 digits, each taken from the set $[0, 1, 2]$ is to be formed. The string should not contain any of the substrings $012$, $120$, and $201$. How many such 6-digit strings can be formed?

---

I really have trouble in using PIE in here. I'm badly needing some clear explanation in the PIE part because it's not what I usually deal with.

I have also a question: 'Does avoiding $000$, $111$, and $222$ instead will still gain the same result?'.

Thanks for all the help in advance :)

Comment: Try seeing how many different 3 digits strings (excluding those) can be formed  then combine two 3 digits ones, but avoiding those again where the two strings overlap?

Comment: $492$ either way, python source code [here](https://tio.run/##PY3BCoMwDIbvPkVubUGk7WCMwZ5EepBNWXQ2JcaDT9/ZDvZfknyQ70@HvClebolzxjURC6CMLESfrZmIYQGM0PfKOq9aUM7bMrx1KrQntfV0zlXqvQrh3sCZxBhF17Vk21ftoAixCP8dXWJ67U/RvwIe0zjI42oAJ4gkMMRDz@VDqW4mjBpNtVS2GFMLTM5f). I'd try recursion for string length and its $2$ leading or trailing digits.

Comment: For the second question, let $a_n$ denote the number of such strings where the last two digits differ, and $b_n$ be the number of such strings where the last two digits are the same.  Then $a_2=6, b_2=3$ and we know: \begin{eqnarray*} a_{n+1}&=&2b_n+2a_n,\\b_{n+1}&=&a_n,\end{eqnarray*} from considering which of $\{0,1,2\}$ you can add to the end of a string of length $n$  to produce a legitimate string of length $n+1$.  Combing you get $a_2=6, a_3=18$ and $$ a_{n+1}=2a_{n-1}+2a_n.$$

Answer (score 2):

Given a string that avoids $000,111,222$ add $i$ modulo $3$ to the $i$'th digit to obtain a string that avoids $012,120,201$.  This is clearly a bijection.

Lets consider all legitimate strings of length $3$ (e.g. those that avoid $000,111,222$):

$011, 022, 100,122,200,211$

and

$001,010,020,002,12,021,101,110,120,102,112,121,201,210,220,202,212,221$.

Notice I have written them in two lists: the first $6$ end $aa$, whilst the other $18$ end $ab$.  In my notation $a_3=18, b_3=6$.  Here $a_n$ is the number of legitimate strings which end $ab$ and $b_n$ is the number of legitimate strings which end $aa$.

Consider a string which ends $aa$ such as $011$.  What can I add to the end, so that it is still legitimate?  I cannot add $1$, but if I add $0$ or $2$ I get a string of length $4$ and ending $ab$: $0110, 0112$.

What about a string ending $ab$?  Consider $001$.  If I add $0$ or $2$ then I get a string of length $4$ ending $ab$: $0010,0012$.  On the other hand if I add a $1$ I get $0011$ which ends $aa$.

This is summed up in the diagram:

[image]

So for each string of length $n$ ending $ab$, we can get $2$ strings of length $n+1$ of type $ab$ by adding a number at the end, whilst for each string of length $n$ ending $aa$ we can get two strings of length $n+1$ ending $ab$, by adding a number at the end.  Thus for $n\geq 3$ we have: $$a_{n+1}=2a_n+2b_n.$$

Similarly, for each string of length $n$ ending $ab$ we get one string of length $n+1$ ending $aa$.  You cannot add any number to a string of length $n$ ending $aa$, to get a string of length $n+1$ ending $aa$ (as $aaa$ not allowed).  Thus for $n\geq 3$ we have: $$b_{n+1}=a_n$$

Combining the two equations, for $n\geq4$ we get:$$a_{n+1}=2a_n+2a_{n-1}$$

The total number of legitimate strings of length $n$ is $$a_n+b_n=a_n+a_{n-1}.$$

We know $a_2=6,a_3=18$. From the recursion we have $a_4=48, a_5=132, a_6=360$.

Thus there are $132+360=492$ legitimate strings.

Comment: Hi @tkf. Unfortunately, I'm still unable to grasp your idea. Could you please suggest me on what topic I'm dealing?? Or what topics should I learn first. I can't find a topic like this in the internet. I'm still confused. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Are you happy with the bijection between strings that avoid $000,111,222$ and strings that avoid $012, 201, 120$?  Are you happy with the definition of $a_n$ and $b_n$?  The idea is quite elementary so there is no theory you need to learn.  However the trick comes up a lot so it is useful to know.  When you are counting strings that satisfy some property, and you want to relate the number of such strings of length $n$ to those of length $n+1$, it is often helpful to partition the strings up depending on how they end.  Then you get a kind of network.

Comment: In this case there are two types of ending to a string $aa$ or $ab$ with $a\neq b$.  If a string ends $aa$ then you can add any number  except $a$ to the end, and your string will now end type $ab$.  Conversely if your string ends type $ab$, then there are two numbers you can add to get an $ab$ type ending, and one number to get a $aa$ type ending.  It is a bit like a Markov process - if you have come across them.

Comment: @hansduran0123 I have added a diagram to show the two states, and how adding each number moves you between them.  In the diagram $a,b,c$ correspond to $0,1,2$ in some order.

Comment: It's all cool though everything's actually really helpful. I know the concept of bijection and the diagram actually makes me see things out. Thank you very much. I going to contemplate on the things you put here. :)

Comment: @hansduran0123 I have added a simpler explanation with examples.  It is a method that comes up a lot for these types of questions, so worth having in your tool kit.  Once you understand it, it is very fast to implement.

Answer (score 1):

You want to avoid 12 properties:
\begin{matrix}
000xxx & x000xx & xx000x & xxx000 \\
111xxx & x111xx & xx111x & xxx111 \\
222xxx & x222xx & xx222x & xxx222 \\
\end{matrix}
The inclusion-exclusion formula is $$\sum_{k=0}^{12} (-1)^k N_k,$$
where $N_k$ is an overcount of the number of $6$-strings that satisfy $k$ properties.  Clearly, $N_k=0$ for $k>4$.
We have
\begin{align}
N_0 &= \binom{12}{0} 3^6 = 729 \\
N_1 &= \binom{12}{1} 3^{6-3} = 324 \\
N_2 &= 2 \binom{3}{2} 3^{6-6} + 3 \left(3 \cdot 3^{6-4} + 2 \cdot 3^{6-5} + 1 \cdot 3^{6-6}\right) = 108 \\
N_3 &= 3 \left(2 \cdot 3^{6-5} + 2 \cdot 3^{6-6}\right) = 24 \\
N_4 &= 3 \left(1 \cdot 3^{6-6}\right) \\
\end{align}
Putting it all together, we obtain
$$729 - 324 + 108 - 24 + 3 = 492$$

Comment: So cool! This is all I've been wanting for. Thanks so much @RobPratt :)